# React router is not working with context API

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

I'm trying to make a redirect when user submit to the form but the redirect is not fired , on the form submit nothing. I want it to redirect to a certain path.

```js
    const submitEmailHandler = () => {
        if (registerInfo.mainData.email) {
          return <Redirect to="/test" />;
        }
      };

      return (
        <EmailContext.Provider value={registerInfo}>
          {props.children}
        </EmailContext.Provider>
      );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

**App.js**

```js
import Main from "./Components/Layout/Main";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./Components/Footer/Footer";
import EmailContextProvider from "./Context/email-context";
import Landing from "./Components/Landing/Landing";
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <EmailContextProvider>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/signup/registration" component={Landing} />
          <Route path="/" component={Main} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </EmailContextProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```